# Blobs created in JS not released after URL.revokeObjectURL

Tags: javascript, html, browser, blazor, blob

I have this simple JS function used to load (and show) images from byte arrays

```
function setElementSrc(element, mimeType, buffer) {
    var blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: mimeType });
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    element.src = objectUrl;
    element.onload = function () {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
    };
}
```

Since the object url gets revoked in onload I would expect there to be no more references to the blob. Yet, when I look into chrome debugger or chrome://blob-internals/ they remain there forever, having one reference. Even when the img itself is gone.

The `URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl)` does work, since after its call the object url is not reachable anymore.

Do I understand something wrong? What am I missing?
Is there a way to see what is still referencing the blob?

Comment: Did you ever log that Blob? Could very well just be the dev-tools itself that's keeping a pointer to it.

Comment: I do no logging by myself. I just use the chrome dev tools and see them remaining under sources. And in chrome://blob-internals likewise

Comment: And you did call the Garbage Collector manually?

Comment: Yes I did. But the blobs did not get collected. They remain

Comment: Wait no, they remain in dev tools. But in chrome://blob-internals they are gone

Comment: So you have your answer then?

Comment: Yes, it is like Kaiido suggested. Only the dev tools keep a reference (or more likely a copy) to the blobs